# Everything in one line

Tags: lua

My example is the below, i found i code in internet, but its a little difuculty to understand it because are everything in one line, there a program or website to uncode it? i mean, add the spaces and lines to make it more readiable?

```
require("libs.Utils")require("libs.Res") require("libs.SideMessage") local adae = false local ddasf = true local ddasfcfa = false local ggsa = {} local fasca = {} local vvsa = {} local ggaw = {} local fefsg = nil local hhasf = true local gggqas = 4000 local bwe = false local bwefqa = {} print(math.floor(client.screenRatio*100)) --[[Config. --If u have some problem with positioning u can add screen ration(64 line) and create config for yourself.]] if math.floor(client.screenRatio*100) == 177 then testX = 1600 testY = 900 tpanelHeroSize = 55 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714 tpanelHeroSS = 20 txxB = 2.535 txxG = 3.485 elseif math.floor(client.screenRatio*100) == 166 then testX = 1280 testY = 768 tpanelHeroSize = 47.1 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714 tpanelHeroSS = 18 txxB = 2.59 txxG = 3.66 elseif math.floor(client.screenRatio*100) == 160 then testX = 1280 testY = 800 tpanelHeroSize = 48.5 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714 tpanelHeroSS = 20 txxB = 2.579 txxG = 3.74 elseif math.floor(client.screenRatio*100) == 133 then testX = 1024 testY = 768 tpanelHeroSize = 47 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714 tpanelHeroSS = 18 txxB = 2.78 txxG = 4.63 elseif math.floor(client.screenRatio*100) == 125 then testX = 1280 testY = 1024 tpanelHeroSize = 58 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714 tpanelHeroSS = 23 txxB = 2.747 txxG = 4.54 else testX = 1600 testY = 900 tpanelHeroSize = 55 tpanelHeroDown = 25.714
```

Comment: I disagree. That is about indenting code that already is on several lines. In fact, the first answer even says it doesn't change the line structure.

Comment: in any case, asking for software tools is off topic.

Comment: You could have formatted it in less time than it took to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if such a program exists, but you can put it into a text editor that supports Lua syntax highlighting. Then, it's mostly a case of hitting 'enter' where the Lua triggers are (things like `local` and `require`, for instance). Lua is nice in that it allows you to put everything on one line, but I can understand how hard that can be to read so you can understand what's being done.